# Problem writing to CSV (German characters) in Spark with UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data set of companies (globally), where there are numerous companies that have foreign names.

I import the parquet data first using:

```
val df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("import path").
```

I do some filtering and manipulation and when I write the data to csv it displays weird symbols even after I specify the encoding.

- SanitÃ¤r Wirth
- KitzbÃ¼hel Country Club
- HotelovÃ¡ Å¡kola SvÄ›tlÃ¡ a StÅ™ednÃ­ odb. Å¡kola Å™emesel

How would I export the data so that the foreign characters are accurately represented??

```
df.coalesce(1).
        write.
        mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
        format("csv").
        option("header", true).
        option("encoding", "UTF-8").
        partitionBy("Region").
        save("path")
```

Comment: " are accurately represented??" what is the meaning of it you want to display them in english ?

Comment: these companies are actually German so the data should have characters like Ä,, Ö, Ü, etc.

Comment: I would venture a guess : are you sure that the output file is incorrect ? It may very well be the text editor you use to visualize the output file that is not using UTF to display the contents. You have to make sure where the "corruption" occurs : is your reading of the parquet file OK ? Or is it when you manipulate the text ? Or is it when you write to a file ? Or is it your text editor that you check your file with ? When in doubt, I tend to open files with an hexadecimal viewer, and check the bytes, not the text interpretation of them.

Comment: @BennyLin My answer is working or not let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to specify correct encoding for German characters. or the editor you are opening is corrupting the characters by its own encoding (may be editor fault). Normally, both utf-8 and iso-8859 will do the encoding in the same way. After chatting to **@GP**I ***I tested below code in utf-8 format also. out put was the same using intellijeditor I opened the text file produced.***

---

#### UPDATE /Conclusion :  The below way using iso or with utf-8 it should work in the same way. That might be OPS text editor by which he is opening might be causing this issue. Where the issue is not an issue at all.

```
 df.coalesce(1).
    write.
    mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
    format("csv").
    option("header", true).
   .option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1") 
    partitionBy("Region").
    save("path")
```

Taken sample german characters data and saved as csv again in file system
Here is example  and code.

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
object GermanCSV extends App {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName(this.getClass.getName).master("local").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val mycsvdata =
    """
      |rank,freq,Infinitiv,Unreg,Trans,"Präsens_ich","Präsens_du","Präsens_er, sie, es","Präteritum_ich","Partizip II","Konjunktiv II_ich","Imperativ Singular","Imperativ Plural",Hilfsverb
      |3,3796784,sein,"","",bin,bist,ist,war,gewesen,"wäre",sei,seid,sein
      |8,1618550,haben,"","",habe,hast,hat,hatte,gehabt,"hätte",habe,habt,haben
      |10,1379496,einen,"","",eine,einst,eint,einte,geeint,einte,eine,eint,haben
      |12,948246,werden,"","",werde,wirst,wird,wurde,geworden,"würde",werde,werdet,sein
    """.stripMargin.lines.toList.toDS


  val csvdf: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", true)
    .option("header", true)
    .csv(mycsvdata)

  println("orginal data")
  csvdf.show(false)

  println("Writing in to a csv file with ISO-8859-1 encoding way , handling german characters")

  csvdf.coalesce(1).
    write.
    mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
    format("csv").
    option("header", true)
    .option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")
    .save("data/iso8859-1")
 }
```

Result :

```
[2020-04-22 10:26:36,598] WARN Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable (org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader:62)
orginal data
+----+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+---------+
|rank|freq   |Infinitiv|Unreg|Trans|Präsens_ich|Präsens_du|Präsens_er, sie, es|Präteritum_ich|Partizip II|Konjunktiv II_ich|Imperativ Singular|Imperativ Plural|Hilfsverb|
+----+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+---------+
|3   |3796784|sein     |null |null |bin        |bist      |ist                |war           |gewesen    |wäre             |sei               |seid            |sein     |
|8   |1618550|haben    |null |null |habe       |hast      |hat                |hatte         |gehabt     |hätte            |habe              |habt            |haben    |
|10  |1379496|einen    |null |null |eine       |einst     |eint               |einte         |geeint     |einte            |eine              |eint            |haben    |
|12  |948246 |werden   |null |null |werde      |wirst     |wird               |wurde         |geworden   |würde            |werde             |werdet          |sein     |
+----+-------+---------+-----+-----+-----------+----------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+----------------+---------+

Writing in to a csv file with ISO-8859-1 encoding way , handling german characters
```

#### Saved csv as per code `data/iso8859-1` not changing data ... like below:

```
rank,freq,Infinitiv,Unreg,Trans,Präsens_ich,Präsens_du,"Präsens_er, sie, es",Präteritum_ich,Partizip II,Konjunktiv II_ich,Imperativ Singular,Imperativ Plural,Hilfsverb
3,3796784,sein,"","",bin,bist,ist,war,gewesen,wäre,sei,seid,sein
8,1618550,haben,"","",habe,hast,hat,hatte,gehabt,hätte,habe,habt,haben
10,1379496,einen,"","",eine,einst,eint,einte,geeint,einte,eine,eint,haben
12,948246,werden,"","",werde,wirst,wird,wurde,geworden,würde,werde,werdet,sein
```

Comment: Not sure what is your point, here. `DataFrameReader.csv(ds: Dataset[String])` performs CSV parsing from a String (not from bytes). Therefore, defining an encoding in the read part is useless. Case in point : `spark.read.option("header", true).option("encoding", "doesNotExistEver").csv(mycsvdata)` works just the same in your code. Which means, IMHO, that your code is equivalent to OP's. Which would tend to prove that the OP actually does not have any issue in its implementation, but in the tool used to perform his check (for ex: it opens a UTF file in ISO LATIN mode).

Comment: using dataframereader.csv I prepared just *test data* with special characters and wrote in encoding ISO-8859-1  to see that source data  is changing or not .  In @Benny-lins  case, He is not able to display the special characters from the source file(parquet)  as it is after he converted that in to csv with utf-8 encoding. so I am asking him to change encoding. For that showed one example with Special German Char.

Comment: But there is no encoding to be specified when you read data from parquet, the parquet format does the encoding itself (or am I mistaken ?). If I'm not mistaken, there is nothing the OP can change to match your code, and the corruption, *if any*, can only occur at the writing stage which is the same as OP's in your answer (again, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: yes you are right there is no encoding specified while reading... where as i did in my example by mistake. while writing we need to specify the encoding `csvdf.coalesce(1).
    write.
    mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
    format("csv").
    option("header", true)
    .option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")
    .save("data/iso8859-1")` I modified the example. But my final intention is to tell that we have to use ISO-8859-1 while writing it.

Comment: Well I see no character that is encodable in ISO 8859 1 that is not also encodable in UTF8. There is no reason why UTF8 would fail when ISO 8859 1 would not. The output encoding may also be a technical requirement so there may not be room for a choice here. I come to the same conclusion once again : the text editor used by the OP fails him by reading a valid UTF file with a ISO encoding, which make it look like the write failed / corrupted the data when in fact it is the control process that fails, and not the production of the output. It is by far t most probable explainaton, until disproven.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212310/discussion-between-ram-ghadiyaram-and-gpi).

Comment: I agree with you after testing in `utf-8` also ouput is same. may be op's text editor issue.

Answer (score 0):

Which Apache Spark version are you using? The encoding option has been available since 2.4.0 as you can see in the [official docs for 2.4.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#csv-java.lang.String-) versus the [official docs for 2.3.4](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.4/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#csv-java.lang.String-).

Also, according to the docs cited above, you should not need to set the encoding if it is `UTF-8`, given that it is in fact the default encoding.